# How to remove substring from string in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am new to Python 3. Currently, I am working on a project that requires ne to go through a csv file (without using the csv modules) and extract numbers. While I have been able to get most of the extracting part done, my problem is that the last number of each line is printed with a `"\n,"` which means I cannot convert it into a float. How can I get rid of this for each row?

I've tried using `.rsplit("\n")`, `.replace("\n", " ")`, `.replace("\\n", " ")`, and have even done the backslash and the n in two separate replace statements, but they still stay there.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
for row in open(filename):
    row = row.split(",") # elements separated by commas
    for i in range(len(row) - 1): # go through each element in the row
        row[i].replace("\\n", " ") # supposed to get rid of the \n at the end
        row[i] = float(row[i]) # str to float conversion
    lines.append(row) # add that row to list of lines
```

Sample csv: `13.9, 5.2, 3.4`

Expected results: `[13.9, 5.2, 3.4]`

Actual results: `[13.9, 5.2,'3.4\n']`

Apologies if I formatted wrongly, this is my first time posting on Stack Overflow. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Check my new answer: I had overlooked one key issue.

Answer (score 3):

### Current code issues

`replace` doesn't work in-place. Instead it returns a string with the replacement done. Hence, for fix #1 you should change your statement from:

```
row[i].replace("\\n", " ")
```

to:

```
row[i] = row[i].replace("\\n", " ")
```

However, the bigger problem is the iteration over the list obtained from the `.split(",")` operation.

In fact, your iteration runs short of 1 element, hence never touches the last item, and thus never removes the `\n`. Let's do some math:

```
row = ['13.9', ' 5.2', ' 3.4\n']
# len(row)  == 3
# len(row) - 1 == 2
# range(len(row) - 1) == [0 1], which will do 2 iterations instead of 3
```

So, fix #2 would be to correct that `for` loop, which should look something like:

```
for row in open(filename):
    row = row.split(",")
    for i in range(len(row)):  # notice the absence of -1
        row[i] = row[i].replace("\n", "")
        row[i] = float(row[i])
    lines.append(row)
```

### Better way

Since every line of a CSV file has an ending `\n`, you might as well strip it *before* you split the columns and perform the conversion `str` to `float` via map, like this:

```
lines = []
for row in open(filename):
    row = row.strip().split(",")  # first remove the "\n" then split
    row = list(map(float, row))   # [13.9, 5.2, 3.4]
    lines.append(row)
```

Comment: I was really hoping this would work but unfortunately it still prints with the "\n" at the end. Thank you for trying though!

Comment: @user12055762 Check my updated answer: I had overlooked one key issue in your original code.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable in Python, so you will need to always assign `row[i]` back to the modified version of itself:

```
for row in open(filename):
    row = row.split(",")
    for i in range(len(row) - 1):
        row[i] = row[i].replace("\n", "")  # CHANGE HERE
        row[i] = float(row[i])
    lines.append(row)
```

Note: You don't need to double escape the backslash in `\n` when using regular string replace.

Comment: Maybe better to use `.strip()` as we don't need whitespace as the string is being converted to a float

Comment: I just tried that and the `.strip()` but it still prints the last element of each row with the '\n' at the end. Thank you so much for the suggestions though.

Comment: Please try: `row[i] = row[i].replace("\n", "")` ... don't replace with a space, replace with empty string.